# This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently

Tags: vb.net, winforms, backgroundworker

I am confused. Yes i understand I can't use the same backgroundworker to do two tasks at the same time. What I do not understand is this. Here is my code (all this thing does is set the marqueeanimationspeed of a progress bar...

```
'THE FOLLOWING SUB TOGGLES THE PROGRESS BAR
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    'CHECK THE STATE OF THE PROGRESS BAR AND TOGGLE IT
    If ToolStripProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0 Then

        ToolStripProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 22

    End If

    ToolStripProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0


End Sub
```

OK, so how long can this possibly take? Doesn't the worker do the task and exit? So I put in a pause (system.threading.thread.sleep(2000)... same problem, made it 20 seconds... same problem.

So I am assuming this is a simple thing I'm missing, but I've spent more than an hour searching and I don't get it.

All I am trying to accomplish here is to start the marquee progress bar while the UI is running something else, and then stop it. I assume I can create another backgroundworker and just use it, but I want to understand why the first one is not done with the task.

Thanks, and again, yes I spent an hour searching and I find all kinds of "solutions" but no explanation as to why this thing is not finished.

OK SO HERE IS THE SUB CALLING THE BGW

```
    'THE FOLLOWING SUB FIRES THE SETTING CONNECTION STRINGS SUB
Private Sub SetCSButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SetCSButton.Click

    'START THE PROGRESS BAR & CHANGE THE LABEL
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Preparing the connection strings..."
    Me.Refresh()


    thread3 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf SetConnectionStrings)
    thread3.Start()

    'STOP THE PROGRESS BAR & CHANGE THE LABEL
    BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Standing by..."
    Me.Refresh()

End Sub**strong text**
```

I had a 20second delay but still the first BGW does not finish. I know this is something simple but I dont understand, that's all I am after here.

I DID change the code and do not use the same methodology as I was trying at the time I wrote this question... What I do not understand is why a simple operation is never, apparently, finishing... having said that, it DOES finish as I was able to show a msgbox using the runworkercompleted event. So, as I tried and failed to convey, thbis is not about the right or wrong way to code, I know it wa wrong and was just trying to be quick and dirty, regardless of that, I am not doing that now, but I do not understand why the BGW is "still working". There must be some simple thing I am ignorant about.

Thanks

Comment: After the Edit: not a whole lot clearer because now Bg2 and Thread3 come int play. But when Bgw1 and Bgw2 somehow refer to the same instance it makes sense, Thread.Sleep() ties up the message-loop so the Completed event cannot be processed.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not in the posted code but where you start the Bgw.

But it is all irrelevant because you should not touch the GUI from DoWork:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(...) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    'CHECK THE STATE OF THE PROGRESS BAR AND TOGGLE IT
    If ToolStripProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0 Then   ' Boom, cross-threading violation

        ToolStripProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 22

    End If
```

I don't think you need a Bgw, thread or timer here. Just change the speed before/after the slow action.

Comment: This is a simple app, so rather than mess with delegates I ignore the cross thread call... probably not "right" I know, but I am the only developer and I know nothing else acts on it. Also, the confusion I am having is why the bgw is not finished, it does almost nothing. I tried delays etc., I assumed it was simply that I could get there fast enough that the bgw really was not finished, but with a 20sec delay in the main thread it HAS to be done right? That's my confusion.

Comment: And also unless I'm missing something, which is quite possible of course... I am trying to let the user know the app is not frozen, what is happening is a DGv is updating and I want the progressbar to sweep. If I do it like you suggest, and I did at first, the code updates marquee speed, nothing happens while the dgv is updated, then it is switched off, so the user sees nothing happen on progressbar. Maybe I am confused here or doing something more basic wrong?

Comment: Only use the Bgw to do non-GUI stuff like loading the data. Setting Marquee properties there is useless. The core/title question is still unanswerable because you did not post the relevant code.

Comment: Post the full code as the cause for the error can not be seen in the snippet you have posted. That said, if you have just suppressed cross threading errors you could have a number of problems, and there is no reason whatsoever to do that. The background worker is designed with this in mind and has the reports progress property.

Comment: Did you get an error after clicked a button "SetSCButton" second time?

Comment: No this was simply click the button once